# Mplot3d - can't sign axies by ax.set_label()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried to code like in tutorials, but it gives no effect. Only matplotlib.pyplot(plt) in operations plt.xlabel/ylabel can sign those axies, but then i can not sign the 'Z' axies(no function for this one). Code:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
z = np.array(zs)
y = np.array(ys)
x = np.array(xs)

plt.xlabel()
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: it's  in the '1'  link. Due to not enough points i can't post screen so stackoverflow put it into imgur and give this super-nonvisible link.  There's also a figure that code creates. But i will give code here too.

Comment: Do not post code as an image! Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and create an MCVE

Comment: Instead of `ax.set_xlabel = ('X')` it should be `ax.set_xlabel('X')`